# Turn an object into its subclass in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I have a `Person` object which contains things like `name`, `email`, `birthdate`, etc.

I also have a subclass of `Person` called `Member`, which contains things like the `yearJoined`, `title`, etc.

In my code, how can I take an existing `Person` and convert it to a `Member`? For example:

```
Member *mem = self.person;
```

I'm getting compiler errors because the classes don't match. But the subclass should inherit all the properties of its parent, so I'm looking for a way to just say "this `Person` object should now be a `Member` object."

Does that make sense?

Comment: Have a "copy constructor" for Member that accepts a Person.

Comment: Is the Person object actually a Member object that was created as a Member and then cast to a Person?  If so, just cast it back.  If not, do what everyone else says.

Comment: (Of course, someone really into the ugliness of Objective-C object internals might know how to actually modify the class pointer to do this.  But it would require that both classes have the same size instance, at minimum.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do that would be to declare an `initWithPerson` class method and a `memberFromPerson` static method in your `Member` class:

```
@interface Member : Person
{
    NSString *title;
...
}

- (id)initWithPerson:(Person *)aPerson title:(NSString *)aTitle;

+ (Member *)memberFromPerson:(Person *)aPerson title:(NSString *)aTitle;

@end
```

And in your implementation:

```
@implementation Member

- (id)initWithPerson:(Person *)aPerson title:(NSString *)aTitle
{
    if (self = [super initWithName:aPerson.name email:aPerson.email birthdate:aPerson.birthdate])
    {
        self.title = aTitle;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (Member *)memberFromPerson:(Person *)aPerson title:(NSString *)aTitle
{
    return [[Member alloc] initWithPerson:aPerson title:aTitle];
}

@end
```

Then when you want to convert your `Person` instance into a `Member`, you just need to call:

```
Member *newMember = [Member memberFromPerson:myPerson title:@"New member!"];
```

Of course you can customize all this depending on how the other variables like title or year joined are required or not (you can create a version of `memberFromPerson:` without any other argument if you initialize everything properly).

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I was hoping for a way without having to copy over all the various properties, but looks like that's what's up.

Answer (score 2):

2 of the 3 most important properties in object oriented are polymorphism and inheritance.

Given a class A, **inheritance** allows you to create a class B inherited from A, which means B inherits all data members and methods implemented in A, plus it gives you the ability to:

- override methods defined in A, specializing its behavior
- add new methods and data members

**Polymorphism** allows an inherited class B to be used wherever its super class A is required.

When you inherit B from A, B "*knows*" what A is. The opposite is not truth, because A cannot know how many and which classes have been inherited from it. So it cannot behave as if it were an instance of an inheritor.

In your case, `Member` is inherited from `Person`, so `Member` can be used in any place where an instance of `Person` is required. But the opposite is not possible, **unless** you know that this is happening in your code:

```
Member *member = [[Member alloc] init];
Person *person = member; // This is ok, person is a superclass of member
...
...
Member *member2 = (Member *) person; // This, although stylistically questionable, is possible because you know person is an instance of Member
```

so you can cast from `Person` to `Member` when you are 100% sure it's an instance of `Member`, even if hold in a variable of type `Person`.

In the following case instead:

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
Member *member = (Member *) person;
```

the compiler won't complain, but most likely you will receive a runtime exception.

To make the concept clear, let me make a simplistic comparison.
A `MobilePhone` is a base class, from which `SmartPhone` inherits from. A `MobilePhone` has some features (you can make and receive calls, send and receive SMS, etc.). A `SmartPhone` behaves like a `MobilePhone`, so you can use it as if it were a `MobilePhone`, but you can also do much more, such as installing apps from the AppStore (incidentally that 'MobilePhone' is an iPhone ;-)), send tweets, read emails, check calendar, weather, etc. And all those things **cannot be done by a `MobilePhone`**.

For a workaround, the (good) solution proposed by @Romain is a common pattern that's widely used. But you have to keep into account is that **it's not a cast**, a new instance of `Member` is created with data copied from `Person`. In some cases that's very important to know.